# Virtual machine hard drive size question

Tags: virtual-machines, file-sharing, hard-drive, network-share

Original Question:
If I am sharing a folder using VMware Fusion, that shared folder is 500 GB, can I create a samba share of that folder with a virtual machine that has a 10 GB HD.  Or would the virtual machine max hard drive size need to be 500 GB.  How would this work?

Rephrase of Question:
I am mounting a remote folder into my virtual machine using VMware Fusion.  I do this after vmware tools have been installed. It is done as so:

In the VMWare Library, edit the Settings of your currently running virtual machine;
Select the “Sharing” settings option;
Add a new folder and share it with Read/Write permissions;
Close the menu dialogue to save your choice.

This folder is now available to the VM at /mnt/hgfs/[NAME OF FOLDER]

I change permissions so that folder is able to be read/write from both mac osx and my VM(in this case Ubuntu Server 9.04 minimal virtual installation)

Say the folder is called Video.

I use a syslink  'ln -s /mnt/hgfs/Video ~/video'

Now I have access to this shared (shared meaning between OSX and the VM, not any form of osx file sharing) folder from my VM or OSX.  So now I can drop video files in this folder from OSX and my VM can now see those files.

Can I use my VM to create a samba share of those files?  How about ftp?  If my Virtual Machine only has a set 10 GB hard drive and my Video folder contains 500 GBs of video files.  (How) Will this work?  Or do I need a virtual machine with different hard drive specifications?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not very clear. Do you simply want to mount your 500GB drive in your VM? What are you actually trying to achieve — it sounds from the convolutedness of your question that you are not even sure about what you want to do, let alone go about doing it.

Comment: Question rephrased...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you wish to use OSX file sharing to share a folder that also happens to be shared to a Fusion VM - is that right? if so then it's the size of the volume that the VM share is on that matters, it has nothing to do with whether there's a VM sharing it or not. If this is the case then it depends on whether you're using OSX client or server, out of the box there's no disk quota'ing in client, whereas there is in the server version. If you meant the other way around, i.e. you want the VM to create the samba share then it will very much depend on the OS being ran inside the VM.

You might benefit from rewriting the question by the way.

Comment: +1 for possibly understanding the question and possibly providing the right answer!

Comment: Question rephrased...

Comment: Thanks for the updated question - to answer your questions; Yes you can, ftp also, the size of shared partition bares no relationship with the base OS disk size so don't worry, it'll just work. Hope this helps.